# How to make different city selects depending of selected country?

Tags: woocommerce

I already used the list of cities in select when the shop was for one country.
Now I need the same for few countries.
What I used for one country

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_city_fields' );
function override_checkout_city_fields( $fields ) {     
    $option_cities = array(
         '' => __( 'Choose your city' ),
       'City 1' => 'City 1',
       'City 2' => 'City 2',
       'City 3' => 'City 3',        
    );      
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_cities;     
    return $fields;
}
```

What I tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_city_fields' );
function override_checkout_city_fields( $fields ) {     
    $option_citiesua = array(
        '' => __( 'Choose your city' ),
       'City 1' => 'City 1',
       'City 2' => 'City 2',
       'City 3' => 'City 3',            
    );      
    $option_citiespl = array(
        '' => __( 'Choose your city' ),
        'City 1' => 'City 1',
       'City 2' => 'City 2',
       'City 3' => 'City 3',    
    );  
    
$billing_country = WC()->session->get('customer')['billing_country'];
 if ( $billing_country == 'UA')  {  
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_citiesua;   
 }  
 if ( $billing_country == 'PL')  {  
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_citiespl;   
 }      
    return $fields;
}
```

I need to get the current country and to use options from different lists.
Or maybe is a better way?